# What crashed into the ocean near Coney Island?

Tags: cloverfield, cloverfield-2008

One of the popular theories regarding the origin of Clover was that something (possibly a satellite) crashed into the Atlantic, awakening the monster.

You can see the item crashing into the water in Rob's video.

[image: splish splash clover was taking a bath]

But the canon comic [Cloverfield/Kishin](http://cloverfield.wikia.com/wiki/Cloverfield/Kishin) revealed that the monster was awoken by submarines sent by the Tagruato corporation.

**What fell into the ocean, and what was the significance of it?**

Comment: @MikeEdenfield also not mine, and i'm thinking about re-editing the photo due to the spelling error on it

Comment: Huh. I'd assumed that it was the egg of the monster itself hitting the ocean.

Comment: I'm almost positive that it was Chekov's MacGuffin, starting the plot off, whilst doing so in a manner that they can explore in the (ill-fated) movie Cloverfield 2. In the original marketing materials (www.tagruato.jp), the thing that fell was a piece of a Tagruato satellite, which is why the submarines were there in the first place. I'm sure there was a story, but unless there's a release or it's baked into the 10 Cloverfield Lane movie, we won't know.

Answer (score 8):

As Vogie mentions in his comment, the movie's [viral marketing campaign](http://www.tagruato.jp/headlines.php?story=news_08_01_03) included an extensive mention of a falling satellite, the ChimpanzIII.

> Tagruato used the Hatsui satellite to try to identify a rogue piece
>   that is thought to have fallen off of the Japanese Government's
>   "ChimpanzIII" satellite. Although Hatsui’s work has not yet been able
>   to confirm the identity of the fallen piece, Tagruato scientists and
>   engineers are busily trying to track and recover the fragment.
>   According to Hatsui data, it disappeared into the Atlantic Ocean late
>   last week.

It has since been confirmed in the Blu-ray special features that what woke the 'Clover' monster was a [submarine sent to investigate the satellite crash](https://sites.google.com/site/midgarddragon/home) rather than the crash itself.